# Get like value in the row as column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table having data showing in picture
[image: Table Image]

When I run
`SELECT * from pb_results where pb_results.winning_numbers LIKE '%130736%' OR pb_results.winning_numbers LIKE '%130737%' OR pb_results.winning_numbers LIKE '%130738%'`
   and get result [image: query result]

result can be multiple rows and how can i know which row is against which like value....
For example in above example i would like to get a column with value 130736... which shows me this is row is against this 130736.... how can i do this?

Comment: normalize the table structure.

Comment: if you always look for three different numbers, you could use three single select-querys. but like @Raymond Nijland said, you should really normalize your structure.

Comment: Add case statement to the select.

Comment: Thanks i know that structure is not good but i can't  change structure.... due to some problems... and also dont want to run multiple queries..m

Comment: P.Salmon bro can you provide some quelrey example because i am not getting how to add case statment...

Comment: Why don't you just parse it afterwards in your code?

Comment: I just want to mention that when you post your question providing a table schema and some dummy data is much better than pictures. Also if you use tools like [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) it is much easier to help you.

Comment: #mcv  sure next time i will use sqlFiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pb.*,  "130736" as search_value from pb_results pb where pb_results.winning_numbers LIKE '%130736%'
UNION
SELECT pb.*,  "130737" as search_value from pb_results pb where pb_results.winning_numbers LIKE '%130737%'
UNION
SELECT pb.*,  "130738" as search_value from pb_results pb where pb_results.winning_numbers LIKE '%1307378%';
```

Will provide you results with an additional column of `search_value` which will have the search info that you request.

Answer (score -1):

You could include a case statement in your select for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int, List_id varchar(2), Person_id varchar(2), Company_id varchar(2));
insert into t values
(1  , 'L1'      , 'P1'        , 'C1'),
(2  , 'L1'      , 'P2'        , 'C1'),
(3  , 'L1'      , 'p3'        , 'C3'),
(4  , 'L2'      , 'P4'        , 'C4'),
(5  , 'L2'      , 'P5'        , 'C5');

select * , 
    case when person_id like '%p1%' then 'p1'
          when person_id like '%p2%' then 'p2'
          when person_id like '%p3%' then 'p3'
    end likeid
from t
where   person_id like '%p1%' or
          person_id like '%p2%' or
          person_id like '%p3%' ;
```

result

```
+------+---------+-----------+------------+--------+
| id   | List_id | Person_id | Company_id | likeid |
+------+---------+-----------+------------+--------+
|    1 | L1      | P1        | C1         | p1     |
|    2 | L1      | P2        | C1         | p2     |
|    3 | L1      | p3        | C3         | p3     |
+------+---------+-----------+------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```